# Getting warning (nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar) while performSegueWithIdentifier from unwind segue method

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios6, storyboard

I have scene from where I call a another modal scene.
Once modal scene completes or on click of ok button on modal scene, I call an unwind segue to return back to main scene. My unwind segue method is defined in the first scene.
In unwind segue method I call another push scene but I get following warning in "nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar" which ultimately crash my application

Answer (score 0):

That error is definitely triggered by send pop view controllers messages more than once at the time. I suggest you to check your code, maybe you are not aware that something are trigger this action. It's difficult to say without seeing your code.

In my case I was popping the view controller after a nsnotification came but I forgot to remove the observer, so the second time my code was performing the pop view controller twice, hence the warning message "nested pop animation ..."